# Issue with CSS in bootstrap 3 "cards" and dynamic content

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm generating bootstrap cards with dynamic content. These are "profiles" for individuals and their pictures are all different sizes. Because of this, I'm modifying the .card class height on each card, with jQuery, to be the  same height as the tallest card on the page. On doing that, the `.card-actions` class (the footer with links) was not positioning correctly, so I set `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0;`. As expected, `.card-actions` is now positioned at the bottom of the card, **but** it doesn't take up the full width of the `.card` class div.

[image]

You can see where the problem lies below:

[image]

```js
var maxHeight = -1;
$('.bio-profile').each(function() {
    maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
});
$('.bio-profile').each(function() {
    $(this).height(maxHeight);
});
```

```css
.card {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.card {
    margin-top: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
.card.bio-profile .card-header {
    background-color: var(--turq);
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
.card span.card-title {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.card .card-image {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.card .card-image img {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.card .card-content {
    padding: 16px;
    border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.card .card-content p {
    margin: 0;
    color: inherit;
    font-size: 14px
}
.card .card-action {
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.2);
    padding: 16px;
    background-color: var(--mesa);
}
.card .card-action a {
    color: #895715;
    margin-right: 16px;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bio-content" id="bio' + i + '" group="' + gSearch + '">
    <div class="card bio-profile show">
        <div class="card-header"><a href="link" target="_blank">name</a></div>
        <div class="card-image"><a href="link" target="_blank"><img class="card-img-top img-responsive bio-thumb" src="img" alt="name-thumb"></a></div>
        <div class="card-content">
            <h4 class="card-title">Group</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Job</p>
            <p class="card-text">Email</p>
            <p class="card-text">Room</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
            <a href="linkedinlink"><span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span></a>
            <a href="twitterlink"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a>
            <a href="facebooklink"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a>
            <a href="NIHlink">NIH</a>
            <a href="publicationslink">Publications</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you present a sample html of card too.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour Sure thing! Sorry, I forgot that. All the cards are generated with dynamic content so I just put placeholder text in the fields for you.

Comment: For me it works fine. Inspect your card-action element in google chrome or Firefox and check if there are unwanted styles from other where rather than your own styles?

Comment: Thanks for checking it out! One question for you though, did it look okay because you only had the one card? It come out okay on mine as well provided I only have one card. The issue comes in when I adjust the heights of each individual card to be the same height as the "tallest" card.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour Hey ali, i've added the picture of what the cards look like when heights of the cards are changed dynamically. This is **without** setting the "card-actions" (the footer with links) class to position:absolute and bottom:0

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing it using "width: calc(100% - 30px)" on the card action element, but i was hoping not to use a band-aid fix.